# Building Kotlin Multiplatform app with Xcode Cloud

Tags: xcode, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, xcode-cloud

as Apple announced that Xcode Cloud is now available for all developers, I tried to set it up for a Kotlin Multiplatform project. The start was a little bit hard tbh. Currently I am facing following problem during a simple test action:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

So I tried to install a jdk during the `ci_post_clone.sh` phase. The output of `java -version` after the installation on the Xcode Cloud is the following:

```
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)
Installed java
```

also `./gradlew -v` output:

```
Showing All Messages
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle 7.4.2

------------------------------------------------------------
Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.2+8-86)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.4 x86_64
```

Nevertheless, I still get the same error. Is this maybe a restriction by Apple?

Any ideas?

Comment: Facing the same issue.. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Sadly, not really. I started releasing the KM part as an XCFramework with SPM and had this in a separate repository. But that is really inconvenient.

Comment: Could you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

Basically we install a JDK through a tar ball into the project folder using `ci_post_clone.sh`. We choose the project folder because we have control over this directory, contrary to for example installing java through brew (where you would have to symlink the java install into a system directory, which isn't allowed (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/making-dependencies-available-to-xcode-cloud)

> Note
> You can use custom build scripts to perform a variety of tasks, but you can’t obtain administrator privileges by using sudo.

This is the script we use:

```
#!/bin/sh

root_dir=$CI_WORKSPACE_PATH
repo_dir=$CI_PRIMARY_REPOSITORY_PATH
jdk_dir="${CI_DERIVED_DATA_PATH}/JDK"

gradle_dir="${repo_dir}/Common"
cache_dir="${CI_DERIVED_DATA_PATH}/.gradle"

jdk_version="20.0.1"

# Check if we stored gradle caches in DerivedData.
recover_cache_files() {
    
    echo "\nRecover cache files"

    if [ ! -d $cache_dir ]; then
        echo " - No valid caches found, skipping"
        return 0
    fi

    echo " - Copying gradle cache to ${gradle_dir}"
    rm -rf "${gradle_dir}/.gradle"
    cp -r $cache_dir $gradle_dir

    return 0
}

# Install the JDK
install_jdk_if_needed() {

    echo "\nInstall JDK if needed"

    if [[ $(uname -m) == "arm64" ]]; then
        echo " - Detected M1"
        arch_type="macos-aarch64"
    else
        echo " - Detected Intel"
        arch_type="macos-x64"
    fi

    # Location of version / arch detection file.
    detect_loc="${jdk_dir}/.${jdk_version}.${arch_type}"

    if [ -f $detect_loc ]; then
        echo " - Found a valid JDK installation, skipping install"
        return 0
    fi

    echo " - No valid JDK installation found, installing..."

    tar_name="jdk-${jdk_version}_${arch_type}_bin.tar.gz"

    # Download and un-tar JDK to our defined location.
    curl -OL "https://download.oracle.com/java/20/archive/${tar_name}"
    tar xzf $tar_name -C $root_dir

    # Move the JDK to our desired location.
    rm -rf $jdk_dir
    mkdir -p $jdk_dir
    mv "${root_dir}/jdk-${jdk_version}.jdk/Contents/Home" $jdk_dir

    # Some cleanup.
    rm -r "${root_dir}/jdk-${jdk_version}.jdk"
    rm $tar_name

    # Add the detection file for subsequent builds.
    touch $detect_loc

    echo " - Set JAVA_HOME in Xcode Cloud to ${jdk_dir}/Home"

    return 0
}

recover_cache_files
install_jdk_if_needed
```

After running the script for the first time, the logs will print the last `echo` in the script to indicate where the Java SDK is located. This value should be set as `JAVA_HOME` in the "Environment Variables" inside the "Edit" section of the workflow.

[image: Environment Variables]

After that, the build will work with the Java SDK and build the artifacts.

Comment: Haven't tried it until now, but looks good!

Comment: Still fails with "Unable to locate a Java Runtime."

Comment: @moshyfawn Could you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I use a very simple script relying on SDK!Man for this

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
brew install cocoapods
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
sdk install java 19.0.1-tem

# cd into actual project root
cd ../../../
./gradlew app:ios:podinstall
```

Note that if you want to use java in an XCode build, which you probabbly do you need to set the following environment variable

```
JAVA_HOME=/Users/local/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
```

Comment: this is working 2024, but add this JAVA_HOME=/Users/local/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
in the workflow in the code cloud

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using an env variable within the Xcode Cloud Workflow, installing a java runtime using brew, and modifying a gradle property.

Within the ci_post_clone.sh, I ran:

```
#!/bin/sh

brew install openjdk@11
```

Within the environment variable section in the Xcode Cloud workflow I added:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11
```

Within my gradle.properties file I added:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11
```

This allowed the application to build successfully within Xcode Cloud.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't even need to change the `gradle.properties` file